# Une Personne Morale... Is it a practical and logical appellation?

Tags: étymologie

I am French and I find that *Une Personne Morale* the first choice of all government forms, it denotes a representative of a company. We have the choice of being a physical or a moral person. The physical is opposed to the moral, in latin moralis means "way of life, behaviour" so, the definition is so abstract that it seems to lack actual semantic logic. Also, ask any intelligent 16 year old what a moral person is, and he will probably be wrong, because he will give you a logical definition.

Is this a case of archaic administrative esoterism? why does it make sense? Isn't it reasonable to write "entitée officielle" instead of something unintelligible like "une personne morale" ?

Comment: Just a remark. FSE is about the French language. If you are a native French speaker, feel free to post your question in French:-)!

Comment: Oh faksalot, i was mistaken because the title of the forum is not written in French, and neither are some of the questions.

Comment: Most questions I know of coming from natives are written in French. Myself, I am not native. Sometimes I post my question in French. Sometimes I am bit lazy and I post in English:-)! When someone asks something in English, usually the answer will be in English; but there is no rule AFAIK. May be a moderator could be more specific. You can post your question for FSE policy here: https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: BTW, what does faksalot mean?

Comment: thanks alot with an accent :)

Comment: I haven't noticed such an accent when French natives pronounce it. So, thanks a lot:-)!

Comment: "Une Personne Morale the first choice of all government forms." What exactly does that mean? Dans le juridique on oppose la personne morale à la personne physique. La personne morale est une société [SA, SARL, etc.] et la personne physique c'est toi et moi. personne morale dans ce sens-là n'a rien à voir avec moral person en anglais.

Comment: Jai cité le sens Latin moralis, vertu, Aucun rapport avec l'Anglais sauf que le site web est Anglais. Depuis quand existe ce terme juridique et quel est son origine?

Answer (score 6):

C'est un terme de droit, voir [personne morale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personne_morale) qui, comme beaucoup d'entre eux, n'a pas forcement une signification compréhensible par tout un chacun. Mais qui est couramment utilisée.

Comment: Personne morale n'est pas un terme couremment utilisé. Société, SI. moins de 1% des Français diraient "personne morale" au lieu de "société" ou "procureur de société"... En plus c'est là première ligne de tous les formulaires les plus courants... Si on monte une société en france, avec des formulaires compliqués, les termes se compliquent... les gestionnaires de société sont ils donc addréssés avec language incompréhensible sans un dictionnaire de droit? est-ce logique?

Comment: @com.prehensible: Ce n'est pas un problème de « logique », c'est un problème de droit administratif. au même titre que l'on a des termes juridiques, médicaux ... Ce sont les termes consacrés.

Comment: personne morale est utilisé dans les contrats et autres contextes juridiques pour décrire une société. une personne moral c. une personne physique. Je sais de quoi se parle puisque je fais des traductions juridiques vers l'anglais. Et Toto a raison. Ce n'est pas tout le monde qui connait la terminologie juridique....

Answer (score 4):

Il n'est pas très étonnant que le sens d'un mot puisse évoluer, s'élargir, se restreindre, voire s'inverser en deux mille ans.

L'adjectif *moral(e)* s'oppose ici à physique avec comme définition ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/morale))

> qui concerne l'esprit, le psychisme, qui est de nature spirituelle.

Il ne me semble pas trop difficile de deviner le cheminement qui a fait de ce néologisme crée par Cicéron pour traduire le grec *ἠθικός* (→ éthique) qui signifie : *qui a trait aux mœurs, au caractère, aux attitudes humaines*, un adjectif associé à la conscience, et donc à la pensée dans ce qui l'oppose à la matière.

Bien que *personne morale* soit un terme juridique consacré, on retrouve le même *moral* dans des expressions courantes et comprises de tous comme *harcèlement moral*, *réconfort moral*, *force morale*...

*Entitée officielle* n'est pas très heureux comme proposition de remplacement. D'abord parce qu'entité, bien que féminin, ne prends curieusement pas de *e* final mais surtout parce qu'on perdrait le sens de *personne* qui est pourtant primordial ici.

On peut faire condamner une personne morale, une personne morale a des droits et des devoirs, alors que ça n'a rien d'implicite pour une entité. D'autre part *officiel* peut faire penser que l'entité émane d'une autorité alors qu'une personne morale peut très bien être privée.

On aurait pu prendre *personne spirituelle* mais un autre sens de cet adjectif s'impose trop pour que ce soit viable.

Peut-être que *personne immatérielle* aurait pu aller, mais c'est un peu métaphysique...